# VS 2012 WDK 8 computer configuration error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wdk

There's a strange error in my Visual Studio 2012 Professional

When I click on Driver > Test > Configure computers  I immediately receive an error 'Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a or one of it dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

How I can fix that error ?

- I already try to deven.exe with /ResetAddIn, /SafeMode, /ResetSettings, etc...
- Re-configured VS 2012 from 'Add/Remove programs' and re-installed WDK 8
- Run VS as user, admin, 'Run as administrator' settings

  I'm running on Windows 7 32bit

Answer (score 0):

That's ok - I found a solution:

- Completly un-install WDK 7 and WDK 8 and anything related to 'Driver' in programs list
- Installed WDK 8 only

  Enjoy :)